# Word for multiple "and"s in a sentence?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

My English teacher told me the word for multiple "and"s in a sentence, but I can't remember what it is. I think it starts with an A or a P. It's been bugging me.

Comment: Why did you place an apostrophe in the word "and's" in your question?

Comment: Answered at _Can I use “and” many times in one sentence?_ (though obviously not the same question: a quasi-dupe).

Answer (score 4):

polysyndeton

> the use of several conjunctions in close succession

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polysyndeton

Comment: related: [hendiadys](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/figures/H/hendiadys.htm).